# HTTP basic authentication using sockets in python

Tags: python, networking, sockets, basic-authentication

How to connect to a server using basic http auth thru sockets in python .I don't want to use urllib/urllib2 etc as my program does some low level socket I/O operations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the easiest place to start is using `makefile()` to get a simpler file-like interface to the socket.

```
import socket, base64

host= 'www.example.com'
path= '/'
username= 'fred'
password= 'bloggs'
token= base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, password)).strip()

lines= [
    'GET %s HTTP/1.1' % path,
    'Host: %s' % host,
    'Authorization: Basic %s' % token,
    'Connection: close',
]

s= socket.socket()
s.connect((host, 80))
f= s.makefile('rwb', bufsize=0)
f.write('\r\n'.join(lines)+'\r\n\r\n')
response= f.read()
f.close()
s.close()
```

You'll have to do a lot more work than that if you need to interpret the returned response to pick out the HTML or auth-required headers, and handle redirects, errors, transfer-encoding and all that right. HTTP can be complex! Are you sure you need to use a low-level socket?

Answer (score 2):

Look e.g. at urllib's [sources](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/urllib.py?revision=81518&view=markup), specifically the `http_error_401` function (and the dispatching around it of course): make the HTTP request, watch for a 401 response, extract its realm, check that its scheme is `basic`, try again with the user and password for that realm (cfr function `retry_http_basic_auth` in that same source file).  Lots of work of course, but that's the price of programming "down to the bare metal" as you require.