# Python socket module: http proxy

Tags: python, sockets, proxy

Hello I'm trying to use protected http socks server with socket module as in the code shown below

`>>> import socket

>>> s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

>>> host = 'http://user:pass@server.com'

>>> port = 8888

>>> s.bind((host, port))`

It gives me error: 

`socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known`

Though if I setup proxy on a Firefox it works fine. What is in the code?

Sultan

Comment: I'm not familiar with `protected http socks server`, I think you mean either an authenticated HTTP Proxy or a SOCKS Proxy. The two different protocols can't easily be run on the same port. Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is because your host is malformed. The Socket host is just a name not a protocol. Your host should be something like:

```
host = 'server.com'
```

The authentication should be done after you connect, i.e., the first message you send is the authentication.

I can't give you the specifics of how to authenticate because that greatly depends on the server you are connecting to. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929532/http-basic-authentication-using-sockets-in-python)